What should I do, if I want the newest stable versions of my packages, preferably from official sources?
I've been using Linux for a while now, but I am a bit confused on what the best way to install packages would be. Since a lot of packages in my distro repositories (I use Pop!_OS) are outdated, should I be getting most of my stuff from Flatpak? Are perhaps the bigger, proprietary packages (like Steam) usuallly pretty recent on the distro-repos? Flatpak also seems to rely a lot on unofficial maintainers. Wouldn't it be better to trust more official sources? How do I know if a package in the distro-repos or Flathub gets abondoned by the developers or maintainers and thus stops receiving updates? Should I, if I want the most recent stable version of a package, add the PPA of the developer to my repos? Doesn't having a bunch of PPAs for every package defeat the purpose of the repo system though?
Ideally, I would want one place for all my packages,with the most recent stable releases, and that the packages are maintained by official maintainers or developers (not sure if that's possible though haha).
Like stated earlier, my distribution is Pop!_OS
Thank you in advance for the Help!

as xkcd once wrote "why have so many ways of installing packages why  don't we have only one" that adds another way of installing it.
as for "official" ways of installing packages some apps on flatpak are community maintained or maintained by the devs themself example discord it's maintained by discord themself and it's the same version as the deb they provide.
As whether you can trust flatpak installing apps via flatpak are about as safe as the apps in your distro's repos. Meaning if you apt it will be the same as the flatpak version, if you don't want to use flatpak you can use ppa's they offer the same as flatpak meaning that it's the newest package instead of being a "stable" version like the one you find in your native package repo,
if you want a distro that has a up to date packages you should think about rolling release distros, rolling release distros are distros that as soon as a update is available for a package it's available for you and its in the native repos some of the most common distros that offer that is arch(based) openSUSE Debian Unstable (also known by its codename "Sid"), if you want something familiar since you are using kde neon, I would recommended debian unstable as it has the same architecture as neon, both being based on debian and use apt so you can easily migrate to debian unstable, if you are feeling adventurous, you could go to arch and try it to get to know arch and it's packages

Thanks for the great answer. Arch does seem more and more interesting to me. Also Nix OS seems to be popular right now. Also should I rather default to using flatpak or the distro-repos?

@fff up to you, if a package isn't your native repos, you have options 1) flatpak/appimage 2) ppa 3) compile it yourself 4) ask your distros maintainer to upload it to your native repos

Thank you. I wasn't sure, if in rolling release, only the os itself gets frequent updates, or the packages in the distro-repos do too. I probably should check them out.

@fff both get updated as soon as a update is available rolling release distros strives to keep its packages as close to the original upstream software as possible. Patches are applied only when necessary to ensure an application compiles and runs correctly with the other packages installed on an up-to-date rolling release system.
